# Mongoose Function - Find count where Something equals Something

Tags: javascript

Im trying to figure out how to run this query to return a list of "Posts" that have a "SavingId" value of an incoming id.

If i run this function it returns the whole count of all savingIds in the Post

```
    exports.postCount = function(req, res) {
        Post.count({

           --->I ASSUME I NEED TO ADD A CONDITION HERE

       },
            function(err, postCount) {
                if (err) {
                    return res.status(400).send({
                        message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
                    });
                } else {
                    console.log(postCount);
                    var data = {};
                    data.count = postCount;
                    res.json(data);
                }
            });
    };
```

id like to modify it to count just a subset of posts where a value "savingId" is equal to an incoming ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see, this question is about Mongoose, not Node as such. The count function is straightforward - just provide it with a query::

```
var target = req.params.....
Post.count({savingId: target}, function(err, count) {...
```